# How do I split the value of a column based on a lookup table?

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, reshape

I have a dataset with ids and associated values:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("1", "2", "3"), value = c("12", "20", "16"))
```

I have a lookup table that matches the `id` to another reference label `ref`:

```
lookup <- data.frame(id = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3"), ref = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "d", "d", "e", "f", "a"))
```

Note that `id` to `ref` is a many-to-many match: the same `id` can be associated with multiple `ref`, and the same `ref` can be associated with multiple `id`.

I'm trying to split the `value` associated with the `df$id` column equally into the associated `ref` columns. The output dataset would look like:

```
output <- data.frame(ref = "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", f", value = "18", "4", "4", "14", "4", "4")
```

| ref | value |
| --- | --- |
| a | 18 |
| b | 4 |
| c | 4 |
| d | 14 |
| e | 4 |
| f | 4 |

I tried splitting this into four steps:

1. calling pivot_wider on `lookup`, turning rows with the same `id` value into columns (e.g., `a`, `b`, `c`.)
2. merging the two datasets based on `id`
3. dividing each `df$value` equally into `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. columns that are not empty
4. transposing the dataset and summing across the `id` columns.

I can't figure out how to make step (3) work, though, and I suspect there's a much easier approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a potential logic. Merge `value` from `df` into `lookup` by `id`, divide `value` by number of matching rows, then group by `ref` and sum. Then take your pick of how you want to do it.

Base R

```
tmp <- merge(lookup, df, by="id", all.x=TRUE)
tmp$value <- ave(as.numeric(tmp$value), tmp$id, FUN=\(x) x/length(x) )
aggregate(value ~ ref, tmp, sum)
```

dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
lookup %>%
  left_join(df, by="id") %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value) / n() ) %>%
  group_by(ref) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value))
```

data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setDT(lookup)
lookup[df, on="id", value := as.numeric(value)/.N, by=.EACHI][
   , .(value = sum(value)), by=ref]

#   ref value
#1:   a    18
#2:   b     4
#3:   c     4
#4:   d    14
#5:   e     4
#6:   f     4
```

Answer (score 2):

A variation of @thelatemail's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69127165/6574038) with base pipes.

```
merge(df, lookup) |> type.convert(as.is=TRUE) |>
  transform(value=ave(value, id, FUN=\(x) x/length(x))) |>
  with(aggregate(list(value=value), list(ref=ref), sum))
#   ref value
# 1   a    18
# 2   b     4
# 3   c     4
# 4   d    14
# 5   e     4
# 6   f     4
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work

```
lookup %>%
  left_join(lookup %>%
              group_by(id) %>%
              summarise(n = n()) %>%
              left_join(dummy, by = "id") %>%
              mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) %>%
              mutate(repl = value/n) %>%
              select(id, repl) ,
            by = "id"
  ) %>% select(ref, repl) %>%
  group_by(ref) %>% summarise(value = sum(repl))

  ref   value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a        18
2 b         4
3 c         4
4 d        14
5 e         4
6 f         4
```